# Is there a way to 'freeze' the app in landscape or portrait mode?

Tags: android, ios, uno-platform

Is there a way to 'freeze' the application in either landscape or portrait mode, so turning the device/phone would not turn the app view but it would stay in either landscape or portrait?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
In you manifest file, just add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for all your activities.

Your activity tag for your launcher activity should look like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"                    
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
     
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
     
</activity>
```

You will have to do this for all your activities. There is no option available to specify it in the application tag.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.

Would you know what the solution for iOS would be?
(Sorry, I should have stated that I needed solutions for iOS and Android)